# YouTube Analytics request returns null

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

So I make a request to youtube analytics that has the following scopes:

```
    'scope'        => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://gdata.youtube.com https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

Using my access token I try to get a list of channel subscribers from the last month, like this:

```
 $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token  . '"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2016-07-01&end-date-2016-08-31&metrics=views&dimensions=day&sort=day';
        exec($command, $result);
```

Even though I succeed in getting the access token and saving the user's credentials, what I get from this request is this:

```
array(0) { }
```

Without any kind of error. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen. If you require more details just ask me. I am on the clock with this problem so I really need some help fast. Any help is welcomed. Thank you all for your time!
This is what I get from making a request in APIs Explorer:

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "day",
   "columnType": "DIMENSION",
   "dataType": "STRING"
  },
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the same data using the API Explorer? I tried it out but I can't get any data since my account doesn't have a YT channel. But, based on the response you have - its different from the [response body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/#response) that's specified on the YouTube Analytics API

Comment: @adjuremods the response body is supposed to be saved in  ["data"]=> (the rest of the array is from my project)

Comment: I do not know how to use api explorer, I'll check it out now

Comment: I executed it using the same parameters in api explorer I updated my question with the response

Comment: I edited how my response actually looks like

Comment: The updated response you provided is similar to mine, I believe the data will be on the `rows` element. I have no data since I don't have a channel. Can you try using other dimensions/metrics to see if it will still return empty? Does the channel you set have any views?

Comment: I did try and I do have views, this is why I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. In my request end-date had a typo:

```
end-date-2016-08-31
```

The correct version looks like this:

```
end-date=2016-08-31
```

And the url I was calling had to have quotation marks. 
So my correct call looks like this:

```
 $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token  . '" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-31 days')) . '&end-date=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')). '&metrics=subscribersGained%2CsubscribersLost&dimensions=day&sort=day"';
```

Thank you for your time!